# Sometimes News web parts are not displayed (SPO modern)

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, newsfeed

I'm using SharePoint Online modern experience.

I have placed several News web parts on the top page of my site (hub site) and they are set to show news posted on different sites.

After granting a lot of user permissions to the site for all employees to use it, some News web parts may not show up when the top page of the site is displayed. Sometimes they will show up after refreshing the screen.

I am troubled by the fact that the News web parts are sometimes not displayed.

Why is it that only News web parts are not displayed?
Is there any solution?

I would appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the browser cache to check if the problem persists.

In addition, please make sure that users have at least read access to news posts from different sites.

Comment: I clear the cache but It's persists. It didn't happen much yesterday, but it's happening quite often today.